# Regex to remove all quote-parts from a text?

Tags: regex, macos, komodoedit

I have a film script and I need to remove all quotes, thus the parts where people are saying something, f.e.: "Martin:".
Does someone know which regex I shoud use?

I'm using scripting language Perl.
So the input I have is a whole filmscript.
The output I want is that filmscript but without the parts where people talk.
So "Martin: I'm hungry." should turn into "I'm hungry."

I tried "\w+\b:" in the find-bar but that selects all instances with a : in it. I tried to use ^ to mark the beginning of the line but it gave an error.

Hower names are not always single names. They can also be Scout Leader or Kid #1 , for example.

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Comment: I tried "\w+\b:" in the find-bar but that selects all instances with a : in it. I tried to use ^ to mark the beginning of the line but it gave an error.

Comment: it's always good to add in your question what you have tried, basic input and desired output. where you're facing problem.

Comment: I'm sorry but I commented on you comment. :-)

Comment: Well it's still not clear which language you're using. how the input strings look like some patterns you should add into your question.

Comment: I changed the question. I'm very new to this so hope it's clear.

Comment: No not all lines start with a name. Sometimes quotes of ppl are split up between lines. Names are not always a single word. Sometimes it is something like: Scout Leader or Kid #1. Names and what they say always separated by :.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can try this**

```
^"[\w\s\d#]+:\s*
```

> Explanation

`^` - Match the start of string.

`"[a-zA-Z][\w\s\d#]+:` - Matches `"` followed by one or more alphabet or space  or digit or `#`followed by `:`.

-`\s*` - Matches zero or more space character.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QwWZxI/7)

Comment: Thanks! Hower not all names are a single word, f.e. Scout Leader or Kid #1. So that does not really work out.

Comment: @Tim better add the possible cases in question. i can write as per question information only.

Comment: Thanks for your help, however cases like Kid #1 are not selected now.

Comment: Thanks you very much!

Comment: I think I'd still do a regex based on not matching characters, as you never know when you'll run across some weird name, or a name using non-English characters.

Answer (score 0):

If the name never contains `:`, you could simply exclude it from the search (based on @code-maniac's answer):

```
^"[^:]+:\s*
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/F2DT9E/1)

`[^:]` matches any characters that are not `:`. You can include any characters that you do not want to match between the [].

Comment: That does not work because not all lines start with a Name:.